# removing pairwise duplicate files

Tags: command-line, files

I have about 700 folders. Each folder contains pairwise combinations of files. I would like to retain only one file per pairwise combination. Any of the pairwise files can be retained as both contain the same content. The files in the folder are not necessarily named in alphabetical order.

```
  Example: 
      Folder1: 
        -> A-B.txt
        -> B-A.txt

      Folder2: 
        -> C-D.txt
        -> C-E.txt
        -> E-C.txt
        -> D-E.txt
        -> D-C.txt
        -> E-D.txt

     Final folder structure: 
         Folder1: 
               -> A-B.txt (or) B-A.txt
         Folder2: 
               -> C-D.txt (or) D-C.txt
               -> C-E.txt (or) E-C.txt
               -> D-E.txt (or) E-D.txt
```

Comment: Are the names actually like that (`A-B.txt` etc.)? And do you want to make the decision based on the file names, or their contents?

Comment: 1. The and B part are actually alphanumerical. Example pairwise filenames would be: abyss345893-oases6546.txt ; trinity4985-soap3095734.txt and so on. 

2. Yes, just with the filenames and not the contents.If that is the easier way. But wouldn't mind deleting based on the contents too.

Comment: is it okay to rename a file if pair doesn't exist? for ex: say X-Z.txt is present but not Z-X.txt, is it okay to rename it to Z-X.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
  ls *.txt | awk -F '[.-]' '{ if (f[$2,$1]) { print $0; }
                              else { f[$1,$2] = 1} }' | xargs rm
```

This works as follows: feed the names of the relevant files to `awk`. For each file, check if a file with reversed name has already been entered in the array `f`. If so, output the file name. If not, put it in the array `f`. Use the output of the `awk` program to delete the duplicate files.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Could you please explain the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` and extract the parts before and after the dash from the file name, testing if the pair exist and if so removing the respective file:

```
find . -name \*-\*.txt -execdir sh -c 'fn=${1##*/};bn=${fn%.*};one=${bn%-*};
two=${bn#*-};pair=${two}-${one}.txt; [[ -f $pair ]] && rm "$1"' boom {} \;
```

The same can be done with a `for` loop (and assuming the shell supports recursive globbing):

```
# if you're using bash run
shopt -s globstar
```

then

```
for f in **/*-*.txt; do
dn=${f%/*}; fn=${f##*/}; bn=${fn%.*}; one=${bn%-*}; two=${bn#*-};
pair=${dn}/${two}-${one}.txt; [[ -f $pair ]] && rm -- "$f"; done
```

Comment: I get the error message as: 

Boom:1: boom Bad substituition 

Boom:1: boom Bad substituition

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -exec \
   perl -wMstrict -le '
      (local $", my $top) = ("", $ENV{PWD});
      for my $curdir ( @ARGV ) {
         my %h;
         chdir $curdir;
            for ( <*.txt> ) {
               my @pair = /^([^-]+)-([^.]+)[.]txt$/;
               next unless @pair;
               $h{ "@pair" }++;
               unlink if exists $h{ "@{[reverse @pair]}" };
            }
         chdir $top;
      }
   ' {} +
```

## sed

```
/bin/ls -1 |
sed -ne '
   1H;1d
   G
   /^\([^-]*\)-\([^.]*\).txt\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\2-\1.txt$/P
   /^\([^-]*\)-\([^.]*\).txt\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\2-\1.txt\n/P
   s/\n\n.*//;H
' | xargs rm
```